# Get Index of First non-Whitespace Character in C# String

Tags: c#

Is there a means to get the index of the first non-whitespace character in a string (or more generally, the index of the first character matching a condition) in C# without writing my own looping code?

**EDIT**

By "writing my own looping code", I really meant that I'm looking for a compact expression that solves the problem without cluttering the logic I'm working on.

I apologize for any confusion on that point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I like to define my own extension method for returning the index of the first element that satisfies a custom predicate in a sequence.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the index of the first element in the sequence 
/// that satisfies a condition.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TSource">
/// The type of the elements of <paramref name="source"/>.
/// </typeparam>
/// <param name="source">
/// An <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> that contains
/// the elements to apply the predicate to.
/// </param>
/// <param name="predicate">
/// A function to test each element for a condition.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// The zero-based index position of the first element of <paramref name="source"/>
/// for which <paramref name="predicate"/> returns <see langword="true"/>;
/// or -1 if <paramref name="source"/> is empty
/// or no element satisfies the condition.
/// </returns>
public static int IndexOf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (predicate(element))
            return i;

        i++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

You could then use LINQ to address your original problem:

```
string str = "   Hello World";
int i = str.IndexOf<char>(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
```

Comment: i'm not trying to be argumentative by saying this, but i thought the point of the question was how to do it without writing a loop so this as the answer is throwing me off (again, not complaining - just curious)

Comment: @EricJ.: I define it generically since I tend to use it in several other scenarios as well.

Comment: @AaronAnodide: Yes, but I do not see a better solution than writing an extension method.  I apologize if I was unclear.

Comment: @AaronAnodide: Valid point, but I interpreted it more liberally as meaning that the OP does not want to write a loop *each time* he/she needs to get the index of the first character that satisfies a condition. Pretty much all of LINQ is written using loops internally; you can think of the above as another LINQ method that was missed in the original release.

Comment: But I think the name (IndexOf) is a little iffy since `String` already has one by the same name.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Why?  It provides a generic equivalent that is more flexible.  `str.IndexOf(...)` will use the non-generic version defined in the framework (and I edited the answer to call the generic version :-)

Comment: @HenkHolterman: The way I see it, my method's semantics are a generalization of `String.IndexOf`, so it's acceptable for it to appear as another overload.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it's acceptable and luckily the `<char>` isn't necessary. Still a name like `IndexOfWhere()` might be clearer.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Fair enough. I don't mind having my methods share the same name as library ones, but I can understand others who would mind.

Answer (score 44):

A `string` is of course an `IEnumerable<char>` so you can use Linq:

```
int offset = someString.TakeWhile(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).Count();
```

Comment: I think it would match framework semantics better if it returned -1 on failure (i.e. when the string is empty, or consists only of whitespace characters).

Comment: Resharper suggests: someString.TakeWhile(char.IsWhiteSpace).Count();

Comment: If it's being used as an offset then returning 0 vs -1 works better.  It will depend on the application but if it's just matching the white space this skips checking for those exceptions.

Answer (score 7):

```
string s= "   \t  Test";
Array.FindIndex(s.ToCharArray(), x => !char.IsWhiteSpace(x));
```

returns 6

To add a condition just do ...

```
Array.FindIndex(s.ToCharArray(), x => !char.IsWhiteSpace(x) && your condition);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [String.IndexOfAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56y4ddbk.aspx) function which returns the first occurrence any character in a specified array of Unicode characters.

Alternatively, you can use the [String.TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx) function which remove all white space characters from the beginning of the string. The index of the first non-white space character is the difference between the length of the original string and the trimmed one.

You can even pick a set of characters to trim :)

Basically, if you are looking for a limited set of chars (let's say digits) you should go with the first method.

If you are trying to ignore a limited set of characters (like white spaces) you should go with the second method.

A Last method would be to use the [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) methods:

```
string s = "        qsdmlkqmlsdkm";
Console.WriteLine(s.TrimStart());
Console.WriteLine(s.Length - s.TrimStart().Length);
Console.WriteLine(s.FirstOrDefault(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
Console.WriteLine(s.IndexOf(s.FirstOrDefault(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))));
```

Output:

```
qsdmlkqmlsdkm
8
q
8
```

Comment: The trim methods can be called without any parameters and in this case it will remove all whitespaces. As for the linq query, you can use the IsWhiteSpace function. I'll update the code sample.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by this [solution of trimming the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695675/7571258), but much more **efficient** by using [`ReadOnlySpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1?view=net-6.0):

```
string s = "   xyz";
int index = s.Length - s.AsSpan().TrimStart().Length;
// index is 3
```

Neither `.AsSpan()` nor `.TrimStart()` create copies of the string, they just store a *reference* to a string character and a length.

- [`.AsSpan()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.asspan?view=net-6.0) is an extension method of `String` that creates a span pointing to the first character of the string. Its length is the total string length.
- [`.TrimStart()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.trimstart?view=net-6.0) is an extension method of `ReadOnlySpan<char>` that creates a span pointing to the first non-whitespace character. Its length is the total string length minus the position of the first non-whitespace character.

This pattern can be used in general to skip over any list of given characters:

```
string s = "foobar";
int index = s.Length - s.AsSpan().TrimStart("fo").Length;
// index is 3
```

---

I did a benchmark of this method and several others from this Q&A, using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) ([my benchmark code](https://gist.github.com/zett42/775a6662dace92237acc824c07b37e93)):

| #### Method | #### Mean | #### Error | #### StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Regex_Compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695583/7571258) | 45.05 us | 0.043 us | 0.034 us |
| **ReadOnlySpan_Trim (this answer)** | **50.24 us** | **0.073 us** | **0.061 us** |
| [String_Trim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695675/7571258) | 94.64 us | 0.458 us | 0.428 us |
| [Regex_Interpreted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695583/7571258) | 114.41 us | 0.224 us | 0.210 us |
| [Regex_StaticMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695583/7571258) (read below!) | 114.19 us | 0.056 us | 0.046 us |
| [FirstNonMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36572281/7571258) | 150.58 us | 0.214 us | 0.190 us |
| [Array_FindIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695794/7571258) | 200.40 us | 1.951 us | 1.730 us |
| [StringExt_IndexOfPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695631/7571258) | 336.31 us | 0.896 us | 0.838 us |
| [Linq_TakeWhile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695641/7571258) | 490.97 us | 0.994 us | 0.930 us |

I didn't expect that `RegEx_Compiled` would be fastest. Actually `RegEx_StaticMethod` should perform equally as `RegEx_Compiled` (because the static `Regex` methods cache compiled patterns), but as BenchmarkDotNet [creates a new process per test run](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/how-it-works.html), that cache doesn't have any effect.

The `String_Trim` benchmark depends on how many characters follow after the first non-whitespace character, because it copies the substring. For short texts, performance could be close to `ReadOnlySpan_Trim`, but for longer texts performance will be much worse. The input text of this benchmark contains 50k non-whitespace characters, so there is already a significant difference.

Comment: Did you benchmark the difference?

Comment: @EricJ. Not yet. This could potentially be even faster than the methods that use predicates, so the result would be very interesting.

Comment: Quick to set up. I'd be interested in the results. https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html

Comment: @EricJ. So I did.

Comment: Interesting result. I'm also surprised that RegEx is slightly faster, at least for the input data in the test. Thanks for putting that together!

Comment: It's only the _compiled_ regex that's faster, and that isn't so surprising. Normal regex is a lot slower.

Answer (score 4):

```
var match = Regex.Match(" \t test  ", @"\S"); // \S means all characters that are not whitespace
if (match.Success)
{
    int index = match.Index;
    //do something with index
}
else
{
    //there were no non-whitespace characters, handle appropriately
}
```

If you'll be doing this often, for performance reasons you should cache the compiled `Regex` for this pattern, e.g.:

```
static readonly Regex nonWhitespace = new Regex(@"\S");
```

Then use it like:

```
nonWhitespace.Match(" \t test  ");
```

Comment: Although using RegEx is a good solution and perfectly valid, I would always avoid using them when there is an easier built in solution. RegEx are naturally heavy in terms of performance.

Comment: @EricJ. you could shorten it to two lines with `var index = match.Success ? match.Index : -1;` (or `(int?)null` or `default(int?)` if you prefer `null` over `-1` for a non-match). @lcfseth good point.  The asker asked for no loop, and "more generally, the index of the first character matching a condition", which looks more like regex than not.  For something as simple as "whitespace" I'd agree with you, but this could be useful in other cases.

Comment: Note that `new Regex(@"\S")` doesn't create a compiled RegEx, but `new Regex(@"\S", RegexOptions.Compiled)` does.

Answer (score 3):

Since there were several solutions here I decided to do some performance tests to see how each performs.  Decided to share these results for those interested...

```
    int iterations = 1000000;
    int result = 0;
    string s= "   \t  Test";

    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

    // Convert to char array and use FindIndex
    watch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        result = Array.FindIndex(s.ToCharArray(), x => !char.IsWhiteSpace(x)); 
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Convert to char array and use FindIndex: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    // Trim spaces and get index of first character
    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        result = s.IndexOf(s.TrimStart().Substring(0,1));
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Trim spaces and get index of first character: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    // Use extension method
    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        result = s.IndexOf<char>(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Use extension method: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    // Loop
    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {   
        result = 0;
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                break;
            result++;
        }
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Loop: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Results are in milliseconds....

*Where s = "   \t  Test"*
Convert to char array and use FindIndex: `154`
Trim spaces and get index of first character: `189`
Use extension method: `234`
Loop: `146`

*Where s = "Test"*
Convert to char array and use FindIndex: `39`
Trim spaces and get index of first character: `155`
Use extension method: `57`
Loop: `15`

*Where s = (1000 character string with no spaces)*
Convert to char array and use FindIndex: `506`
Trim spaces and get index of first character: `534`
Use extension method: `51`
Loop: `15`

*Where s = (1000 character string that starts with "   \t  Test")*
Convert to char array and use FindIndex: `609`
Trim spaces and get index of first character: `1103`
Use extension method: `226`
Loop: `146`

> Draw your own conclusions but my conclusion is to use whichever one
>   you like best because the performance differences is insignificant in
>   real world scenerios.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of solutions here that convert the string to an array. That is not necessary, individual characters in a string can be accessed just as items in an array.

This is my solution that should be very efficient:

```
private static int FirstNonMatch(string s, Func<char, bool> predicate, int startPosition = 0)
{
    for (var i = startPosition; i < s.Length; i++)
        if (!predicate(s[i])) return i;

    return -1;
}

private static int LastNonMatch(string s, Func<char, bool> predicate, int startPosition)
{
    for (var i = startPosition; i >= 0; i--)
        if (!predicate(s[i])) return i;

    return -1;
}
```

And to use these, do the following:

```
var x = FirstNonMatch(" asdf ", char.IsWhiteSpace);
var y = LastNonMatch(" asdf ", char.IsWhiteSpace, " asdf ".Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trim, get the first character and use IndexOf.

Comment: Trim creates a copy of the string.  Not ideal, but functional.

Comment: Better to use TrimStart and see how much shorter the resulting string is. Still a copy is created.

Comment: @Eric J., that is why I said this is not the best solution. But it is simple and can be wrapped in an extension method. There are a lot of solutions here that are also good (and I  would probably choose the one with the best readability)

Comment: Love the self comment :). Once you have trimed the string from the start using the StartTrim function, you just need to take the difference between the two lengths to get the index.

Comment: Even if you use linq, a copy will be created.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a very simple solution**

```
string test = "    hello world";
int pos = test.ToList<char>().FindIndex(x => char.IsWhiteSpace(x) == false);
```

pos will be 4

you can have more complex conditions like:

```
pos = test.ToList<char>().FindIndex((x) =>
                {
                    if (x == 's') //Your complex conditions go here
                        return true;
                    else 
                        return false;
                }
            );
```

Comment: You can shorten this to `return (x == 's');`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try this:

```
string stg = "   xyz";
int indx = (stg.Length - stg.Trim().Length);
```

Comment: That creates a copy of the string.  Not ideal in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Also, like the other answers that use the same approach, you need `TrimStart` not `Trim` or your calculation is vulnerable to producing the wrong length difference by including _trailing_ whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Something is going to be looping somewhere.  For full control over what is and isn't whitespace you could use linq to objects to do your loop:

```
int index = Array.FindIndex(
               s.ToCharArray(), 
               x => !(new [] { '\t', '\r', '\n', ' '}.Any(c => c == x)));
```

Comment: .NET defines what is and isn't whitespace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx.  Would not stray from that definition without a domain specific reason to do so.

Comment: Yes, I agree - I just learned this from this thread - thanks!