# Get index of next non-whitespace character in string

Tags: c#, string, linq

Given the following string as an example:

```
"ABC  DEF    GHI"
```

How can I find the index of the next non-whitespace character if I wanted to start my search from index 8 (the first space after the F)?

Is there a "neat" way I can achieve this without reverting to a simple for loop comparing with Char.IsWhitespace(), or taking a substring and using a solution from [Get Index of First non-Whitespace Character in C# String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695501/get-index-of-first-non-whitespace-character-in-c-sharp-string)

(btw when I say "neat" above I'm not keen on getting into a discussion as to why I may or may not think the solutions I've mentioned are "neat" - just interested in learning something new thanks!)

Comment: _"Is there a neat way...I'm not keen on getting into a discussion as to why I may or may not think the solutions I've mentioned are 'neat'"_ - then that makes us hard to know how to reply.  In any event, we're **not a code-writing service**.  _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: What's wrong with `String.IndexOfAny`?

Comment: @Roy Thanks for the comment but I was just trying to learn something new and given that I already knew a couple of ways of solving this I wanted to point that out and see if anyone had any other suggestions.

Comment: @GertArnold I think with IndexOfAny you need to specifically supply all the characters you might want to find in a Char array. It would work if I did that but I'd rather be able to specify something like !IsWhiteSpace.  Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the following answer from Henk Holterman. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12695641/894095. You can substring your string to start from a specific point and then use the TakeWhile() extension as mentioned in the link. *just noticed you already reference this page". I prefer that as the solution.

Comment: @GertArnold Why rebuild a method that .Net already supplies? Because BCL methods like Trim does not take this approach?

Comment: @IvanStoev Not sure what you mean by that. But I think this point of using existing .Net methods is a bit underestimated. I've had a period that I used some extension methods that basically provided my own syntactic sugar around existing methods (like String.Format). But when it came to refactorings and transplanting code to other libraries I suddenly had to drag along this library containing my utility methods. My code had become less interchangeable and less self-explanatory. This has made me more wary of using such "handy" additions.

Comment: @GertArnold I meant that implementation of the `String.Trim`, `String.TrimStart` and `String.TrimEnd` is using a plain `for` loops rather than trying to reuse `IndexOfAny`. For the second part, all the world including .NET framework is moving to library packages rather than a monolithic BCL and nobody complains about that. Also we cannot expect/wait BCL to provide us with everything. I would agree if there was a standard .Net supplied method, but there isn't. `IndexOfAny` is just not for this case. Anyway, these are just my thoughts, thanks for sharing yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a "neat" way I can achieve this

Here it is:

```
void Foo(string s)
{
    int index = s.IndexOfNonWhitespace(8);
}
```

Not compiling? Well, you asked for a "neat" way and I just showed it. There is no such "standard" way provided by the BCL, but that's why the programmers and extension methods exist.

So, in some common place you will write once something like this and then use it anytime and anywhere you want:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int IndexOfNonWhitespace(this string source, int startIndex = 0)
    {
        if (startIndex < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex");
        if (source != null)
            for (int i = startIndex; i < source.Length; i++)
                if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(source[i])) return i;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

If you say the **implementation** is not "neat", it does not need to be - take a look at the http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: I'm going to go with this answer as you do end up with "neat" code. I really like @Tao's solution below too due to the simplicity of it. Apologies for such a subjective question.

Comment: "Linq"-ers! It's just not for that. Highly inefficient. Simple? Hmm, will you remember it the next time you need it? And even remembering, repeat all that Skip, Take, First, Blah all the time? [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) my friend.

Comment: original question asks to not using loops. I'm wondering why this answer is accepted as there is a better answer using Linq in this post

Comment: @MohammadSanati The original question ask to not using loops at the **call** site. What about "better using Linq", you better learn more what is Linq about before doing such statements!

Comment: Disagree with your comment.

Comment: @MohammadSanati That's your right. But if you wish to improve yourself, use the http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ to see how the professionals do the things. Also take a look at this link https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Contribute and especially the **Avoid LINQ.** line. Have a nice day.

Comment: @MohammadSanati You have a point wrt the use of the for loop, however, Tao's answer creates a substring with the Skip method so strictly speak neither answer fully conforms with my original query. Given this and the fact that my original question was probably too subjective I chose this answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the index you want to start from is 8, you can use this:

```
string text = "ABC  DEF    GHI";
int index = text.IndexOf(text.Skip(8).First(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
```

Basically, you skip the first 8 characters, take the first that it's not white space and get its index. It's not the most efficient way, thought, but it's really readable.

If the starting index is not fixed, you will have to find that index first and inject it into the expression.

Comment: I do think the whitespace-positions should not be hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

This uses LINQ only:

```
string str = "ABC  DEF    GHI";

int result = str.Select((c, index) => { if (index > 8 && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) return index; return -1; })
                .FirstOrDefault(i => i != -1);

Console.WriteLine(result == default(int) ?  "Index not found" : result.ToString());   // 12
```